# R: How to leave only one value in a string by condition / match?

Tags: r, datatable

I have several concatenated values ​​on one row. 
For example,

```
ID    Country    Language

1    Ireland     "English", "French"
2    India       "Indian (Hindi)", "English"
3    Cyprus      "Greek", "Turkish"
4    Canada      "English", "French"
```

For the strings in the `Language` column, where besides other values ​​the value `"English"` is found, I should leave only `"English"` value.

I want to obtain a such dataset:

```
ID    Country    Language

1    Ireland     "English"
2    India       "English"
3    Cyprus      "Greek", "Turkish"
4    Canada      "English"
```

How can I do this with `data.table` package?

Comment: Is it a list columns?

Comment: Plesae follow the instructions at the top of the [tag:r] tag when posting, particularly regarding the use of `dput`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it is a `list` column, loop over the `list` and use an `if/else` option to return "English" if it is found or `else` return the `vector`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
df1 %>%
     mutate(Language = map(Language, ~ if("English" %in% .x) "English" else .x))
#  ID Country       Language
#1  1 Ireland        English
#2  2   India        English
#3  3  Cyprus Greek, Turkish
#4  4  Canada        English
```

---

Or using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, Language :=  lapply(Language, 
           function(x) if("English" %in% x) "English" else x)]
```

---

If it is a single string, use either `grep` or `str_detect`

```
library(stringr)
df2 %>%
     mutate(Language = case_when(str_detect(Language, "English") ~ 
                    "English", TRUE ~  Language))
```

---

With `data.table`

```
setDT(df2)[grepl("English", Language), Language := "English"]
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(ID = 1:4, Country = c("Ireland", "India", "Cyprus", 
"Canada"), Language = list(c("English", "French"), c("Indian (Hindi)", 
"English"), c("Greek", "Turkish"), c("English", "French"))), row.names = c(NA, 
-4L), class = "data.frame")
```